# Is "using which" proper English?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is the phrase "using which", as in

> John has a car, *using which* he drives to work every day.

proper English? Is it interchangeable with "with which"?

Comment: Hello, 398. 'Using which' is fine per se, but would be unidiomatic here. 'John has a car, in which he drives to work every day.' or 'John has a car, which he drives to work every day.' However, 'John has a new lawn mower, using which he can mow the large field in a third of  the time it used to take him.'

Comment: But it is not interchangeable with _with which_, except in this sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you provide an example where the two are not interchangeable?

Comment: _He has a new tuba, using which is prohibited after 6_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, that is not a structure with which I  would construct a sentence....

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments from @Edwin Ashworth, I give my suggestions here.

'John has a car, which he drives to work every day.'

'With' should not be used in the above sentence but is required if we say

'He has a prosthetic left hand, with which he drives to work every day.'

As @John Lawler said, 'with which' and 'using which' are not generally exchangeable.

I believe the latter can replace the former more frequently than the other way round.